# functions of random variables are independent => random variables are independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I saw this on a Quora post https://www.quora.com/Are-functions-of-independent-random-variables-also-independent-to-each-other.

I understand that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent. This doesn't require math and is intuitive for me because if $X$ doesn't affect $Y$, then $f(X)$ also doesn't affect $f(Y)$.

The answer in the Quora post mentions that the reverse is not true, and gives the example that if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, then $f(X)=X$ and $g(X,Y)=Y-X$ are independent. I don't understand how $f(X)$ and $g(X,Y)$ are independent when both $f()$ and $g()$ involve $X$. Furthermore, if $X$ affects $Y$, then clearly $f(X)$, which is defined to be $X$, affects $g(X,Y)=Y-X$? Can someone explain?

If this example is wrong, could someone provide an example of $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ being independent when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest example is a constant random variable. Every constant is a function of every random variable, and every constant is independent of every random variable (including itself).

So if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, then e.g. $f(X)=0$ and $g(Y)=0$ are nevertheless independent.

You write “I don't understand how $f(X)$ and $g(X,Y)$ are independent when both $f()$  and $g()$ involve $X$”; so perhaps you’re not so much interested in random variables that are functions of $X$ and $Y$ but in random variables that somehow “involve” $X$ and $Y$.

The example from the Quora post is wrong; $Y-X$ will generally not be independent of $X$. For example, if $Y=-X$, then $Y-X=-2X$, which is not independent of $X$ unless $X$ is constant.

An example with non-constant variables: Let $X$ and $Y$ both be numbers with two binary digits. Their twos digits are the same, determined by a common coin toss, whereas their ones digits are independent, determined by independent coin tosses. Then $X$ and $Y$ are clearly dependent; but their ones digits (which are functions of them) are independent.

Comment: A couple of questions. A random variable is defined as a function that maps from the sample space to real numbers. If the random variable $f(X)$ maps all $x_i\in X$ to zero, is it still random?

Also, the example given in that Quora post is wrong, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user5965026: I expanded the answer. As regards constant random variables: You ask whether they're still "random". I don't know whether there's a formal definition of "random". You correctly cite the definition of "random variable", and it clearly applies to constant random variables, so regardless of whether you consider them "random", they are certainly random variables.